# Get latest version number from sonatype API for a Maven library

Tags: java, maven, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I am new to publishing library to Maven Central repo. I have pushed a library to Maven Central using the following configuration

```
<repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
</repository>
```

The library is uploaded on maven Central and I am able to access it as well. Here is the link https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.roneetshaw

Now my next step is to get an API from maven/sonatype whose response should be the latest version present on Maven just like bintray does https://api.bintray.com/search/packages/maven?repo=fnproject&g=com.fnproject.fn&a=fdk (example). I am not sure if there is any API to give the latest version of a library from sonatype or not.
Please help if there exist an API, I tried multiple documentation but nothing seems to be working for me